# Avoid capturing unwanted optional words in regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following example text

```
text = '. Double-Decker advances to 1st on throwing error. Chris Parmelee to 3rd.'
```

I want to capture the following information

```
['Double-Decker',  '1st']
['Chris Parmelee', '3rd']
```

I am trying the following regex

```
'\. ([A-Za-z\'\-\s]*) (?:advances)*to (1st|2nd|3rd)'
```

But it is matching

```
['Double-Decker advances', '1st']
['Chris Parmelee'        , '3rd']
```

How should I be dealing with the unwanted optional word `advances`?

Comment: What language / platform?

Comment: Using the re module in Python. I wasn't sure whether to make it language specific and write it as Python code, but decided against it.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
\. ([A-Za-z\'\-\s]*?) (?:advances )*to (1st|2nd|3rd)
```

In your regex there are two small errors:

1. `*` operator is greedy: you should use `[A-Za-z\'\-\s]*?`
2. `advances` does not have a space after, so it won't ever match "advances to".